# Async Tasks in jBPM with Custom Work Item Handlers

Tags: spring, executorservice, jbpm, kie-server

I'm having some issues with making async jBPM custom tasks within my bpm process. My custom task relies on my CustomTaskHandler class that looks something like this

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component("CustomSpringTask")
public class CustomTaskHandler implements WorkItemHandler {

    private final RuntimeDataServiceBase runtimeDataServiceBase;

    private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    public void executeWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
        //new Thread(() -> executeLogic(workItem, manager)).start();
        executeLogic(workItem, manager);
    }

    public void abortWorkItem(WorkItem workItem, WorkItemManager manager) {
        manager.abortWorkItem(workItem.getId());
    }
}
```

SN: I clearly tried the Thread path but it's not a solution I can use in my use case

This works perfectly fine when using normal non-async tasks. However when making a task async, the application logs this line before calling the `executeWorkItem`

> 2021-07-28 12:27:44,641 [WARN ]
> org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.AsyncEventNodeInstance       - No
> async executor service found continuing as sync operation...

This is probably due to the fact that I never created an Executor service. I've opened the default  `AsyncWorkItemHandler` that uses the `ExecutorService` class to schedule the command execution.

So I have 2 doubts:

1. Should I extend the AsyncWorkItemHandler (although I'm concerned on the customizability of the class if I extend it)
2. Should I simply replicate the code within it and add the custom parts

On the second point then I may ask what is the CommandClass that is required by the ExecutorService, and where to instantiate this ExecutorService and on which class it depends.

I found little to no documentation about it on internet. If anyone could point me out to a plausible solution or documentation that would be great

Right now my project is using this setup:

- Spring Boot
- 7.52.0 Kie-Server

Comment: do you use spring-boot-starters for jbpm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBpm requires ExecuterService to run async tasks. if you're using kie group provided spring boot starters then you can simply enable the executor by setting this property in your application.properties file.

```
jbpm.executor.enabled=true
```

more about jbpm's async execution [here](https://docs.jbpm.org/7.55.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_jbpmasyncexecution)

checkout spring-boot-starter for jbpm at [github](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/main/kie-spring-boot/kie-spring-boot-starters/jbpm-spring-boot-starter-basic)